# Statsmodels - 'corrected predictors' on log-linear models?

Tags: regression, log-linear

I'm currently working through an econometrics book , and in the section about `log linear models` it is stated that predictions
made with `exp(b1 + b2x + σ2 / 2)` are preferable to `exp(b1 + b2x)`

The software that I am using is the `statsmodels` python package. And the `.predict` function on my regression model seems to be using the 'wrong' predictor.

I've been unable to find any kwargs / alternative functions that provide 'corrected' predictions.

Does the `statsmodels` package not provide this functionality? And if so, is it because the authors disagree with the 'corrected predictor' or am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: You should ask authors "is it because the authors disagree with the 'corrected predictor'".

Comment: I assume it doesn't you have to insert the constant multiplier yourself. you might also want to look at duan's smearing estimator.

Comment: @user158565.  You're right ofcourse. I suppose a better way to phrase that sentence would have been something like "is their method controversial / contested?"

Comment: its not controversial ( E(exp(z) <> exp(E(z)) ), but its only 'correct' if the errors  (in log transformed data are normal).duans's smearing is an approximation to allow for non-normal errors ... so the question is which is the better approximation in any particular situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log linear model: $log(Y)\sim N(X\beta,\sigma^2)$. Following log-normal distribution, we have $E(Y)=exp(X\beta+\frac 12 \sigma^2)$. But $\bar Y(X) = exp(X\hat\beta+\frac 12 \hat\sigma^2)$ is biased estimate of $E(Y|X)$ even $\hat \beta$ and $\hat \sigma^2$ are the unbiased estimates of $\beta$ and $\sigma^2$, because the non-linearity. But it is asymptotic unbiased estimate.

It is possible to using Taylor formula to decrease the bias duo to non-linearity. There is no other alternative functions.

Check the manual of statsmodels to see if it provide the correct function. Currently, the incorrect (free) things on the internet/website are very common.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!